# Error "End tag fieldset seen, but there were open elements.”

Tags: php, html, css, tags

I was running the W3C validator on the internal page of site and I received this error regarding fieldset tag:

**End tag fieldset seen, but there were open elements.**

```
</fieldset>
```

Please help me with the corect code.

**My code:**

```
<div class="login_header">
                  <form name="form_login" id="form_login" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>login">
            <fieldset>
                      <input type="text" value="" id="user_name" name="user_name" placeholder="Email/Username"/>
                    </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                      <input type="password"  value=""  id="password"  name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                    </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="loginBtnHld">
                      <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" id="btn_login_submit"  value="Login"/>
                      <input type="button" value="Join Free" onClick="window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>registration';">
                      <div class="login_links"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>forgot-password">Forgot password?</a>
                    </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's a missing `</div>` after `</a>` and before `</fieldset>`.

```
    <div class="login_links"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>forgot-password">Forgot password?</a>
</fieldset>
```